# Notifications in webapplication using mysql servlet and jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

I am developing a webapplication which is a cab booking system.

The working is when the customer books a cab the request information will sit into the database. The admin will view it in the web-application and book cab for the customer. 
What I want to do is the admin must get a notification that will show the total number of requests received for every 1 min.

How can I do this? What is that I need to use for doing this?

I'm using servlets,jsp and mysql.

Any help would be much appreciated!Thanks!

Comment: did u save the customer details in db?

Comment: yes Im also able to fetch it in the front end but I want to add notification so that it will notify the admin everytime there is a new request

Comment: In facebook we would have seen the notification that indicates the number of updates and events I want the same concept but dont know how to go about! Is their any API or plugin for notifications?

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain the time-stamp feature in database side,based on time-stamp we will get the latest requests comming from customer.and also you need to use the ajax calling.